# Using C++ functions in Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I'm trying to import some functions created in a C++ library, to be used in delphi. Here is the library i'm trying to use: https://github.com/NGSolve/netgen/blob/master/nglib/nglib.h

I've looked around on google, and found that i've to create a .dll file out of this header file and then, somehow, import hese functions in delphi. The problem is i don't know how i can do any of this!

Can you guys help me out? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There is a lot of info on my website about that: [Using C object files in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html), [Using C++ objects in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html) and perhaps some more.

Comment: The purpose of the code is to make the header file usable for programs that *use* the DLL (__declspec(dllimport)) as well as for *generating* the DLL (__declspec(dllexport)), depending on the  #define of `NGLIB_EXPORTS` or `nglib_EXPORTS` somewhere else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two main ways to do this. Both require you to generate a DLL out of the code. I can't give a detailed explanation on how to do this. But on my website I do give you the details and some sample code. See links below.

The two main ways are

- **Flatten the object**. Wrap each method of the object into a plain function and export that from the DLL. The object is simply passed along as some kind of handle or untyped pointer. You can't use the object directly, so no need to type the pointer or handle. *This is the easiest solution, but not as convenient for the user of the DLL as the next one:*
- **Turn your object into a COM interface** and write a function to instantiate that. *This is far from easy, but makes the DLL much easier to use.*

Both ways are described in my article [Using C++ objects in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html).

You can find some more info in other articles of mine:

- [Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html)
- [DLL dos and don'ts](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html)
- [Using C object files in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html).
  *If these are **not** compiled with C++Builder, you may be lucky that you can do without the DLL and link to object files directly, using the flattening method. But I never tried that.*

Comment: Thank you for your post! I'll look into it!
By the way, can you explain what is the purpose in the code in my edited first post? (it's part of the library file in https://github.com/NGSolve/netgen/blob/master/nglib/nglib.h

Comment: The header *.h* file tells the C++ compiler what functions it is linking to. The cpp files contain the implementation code, and must be compiled into object files or a library. All that together than is then linked into a program or DLL. Just read the article and related articles. It is not very simple, but not so hard either. It just takes some time to get acquainted with the details of what to do. It is some work alright.

Comment: Note: You need more than the *.h* file. You need the entire code in the GitHub repository (you can download it as a *zip*) from https://github.com/NGSolve/netgen/tree/master/nglib . The *.h* file is only one of the files the C++ compiler needs to generate an executable. You even have to write some more C code in order to be able to use the actual code in the *.cpp* files.

Comment: It looks as if what you get there may not be enough to generate a DLL. I see a number of files being referenced by the code that are not in the repository. You probably need the code of some other repositories of the author as well. Good luck with finding and then compiling that, especially if you have never done that before (FWIW, take a look at the make file). If I were you, I would try to find other code.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use plain C API interfaces in Delphi so far. So maybe try to wrap the C++ API with plain C function calls first.

Comment: I understand.. Basically this is a meshing tool (netgen), and i want to use its functions in my delphi application. By what i understood, firstly i've to make a C wrapper of this header file, compile it into a dll and then i can use it in delphi?

Comment: @MafiaSkafia Yes, that's what you'll need to do.

Comment: Here are couple good starter videos - easy to follow.  [C++ Builder - Dynamic Link Libraries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8fwLdWigI0) and [C++ Builder - Static Libraries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEXgDo4YiGk).